# How to perform arithmetic to sort a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists consisting of two numbers each.

```
[[2, 3], [7, 8], [3, 5]]
```

I would like to sort them based on dividing each:

eg 2 / 3 (0.666), 7 / 8 (0.875) 3 / 5 (0.6)
to output:

```
[[3, 5], [2, 3], [7, 8]]
```

I'm assuming I will be using lambda somehow, but I don't know how to write it correctly. Something like this, but this just sorts by the values:

```
list_of_lists.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
```

How do I perform the arithmetic?

Answer (score 10):

```
lists = [[2, 3], [7, 8], [3, 5]]
lists.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0]/x[1]))
print(lists)
```

Comment: Sidenote for python 2.x users: Here you have to convert one of the operants to a floating point.
eg:
`float(x[0])/x[1]`

Comment: Thanks @cbo for adding Sidenote for `python 2.x `users .

Comment: I believe cbo was implying that you may want to edit your answer to reflect that note. After all, the comments won't necessarily be around forever.

Answer (score -1):

May this one helpful for you.

```
a=[[2, 3], [7, 8], [3, 5]]
print (sorted([a[i][0]/a[i][1] for i in range(len(a))]))
```